# Aplicar condição dependendo do valor

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

No *script* abaixo, necessito usar uma condição apenas se o campo estiver preenchido (linha está comentada no *script* abaixo). Se não, esta condição não deve fazer parte da *query*. Há alguma forma de fazer isto via *SQL*?

```
SELECT DISTINCT SB2.B2_FILIAL,SB2.B2_COD,B1_DESC,SB1.B1_TIPO,SB2.B2_LOCAL,CASE WHEN SD3.D3_UM = ' ' THEN SB1.B1_UM ELSE D3_UM END D3_UM,
    (SELECT CTT.CTT_DESC01 FROM CTT010 CTT WHERE  CTT_CUSTO = SUBSTRING(' ',1,5) AND CTT.D_E_L_E_T_= ' ')  AS CTT_DESC01 
FROM SB2010 AS SB2 
INNER JOIN SB1010 AS SB1 ON SB1.B1_COD = SB2.B2_COD AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_= ' ' 
LEFT JOIN SD3010 AS SD3 ON SB2.B2_FILIAL = SD3.D3_FILIAL AND SB2.B2_COD = SD3.D3_COD AND SB2.B2_LOCAL = SD3.D3_LOCAL AND SD3.D_E_L_E_T_= ' ' 
WHERE  
(SB2.B2_FILIAL = '0301' 
AND SB2.B2_LOCAL BETWEEN '03' AND '03' 
AND SB2.B2_COD BETWEEN ' ' AND 'zzzzzzzzzzzz' 
AND SB1.B1_TIPO NOT IN ('MO','SV') 
AND SB1.B1_TIPO IN ('MP') 
AND SB1.B1_MSBLQL IN ('2') 
--AND SD3.D3_CC BETWEEN '' AND 'zzzzzzzzz' ///SE D3_CC <> '', ENTÃO ESSA LINHA FAZ PARTE DA CONDIÇÃO. SE FOR EM BRANCO, ELA NÃO DEVE FAZER PARTE
AND SB2.D_E_L_E_T_= ' '
AND SB2.B2_QATU >= 0.001 ) 
OR 
(SD3.D3_FILIAL = '0301' 
AND SD3.D3_LOCAL BETWEEN '03' AND '03' 
AND SD3.D3_COD BETWEEN ' ' AND 'zzzzzzzzzzzz' 
AND SB1.B1_TIPO NOT IN ('MO','SV') 
AND SB1.B1_TIPO IN ('MP') 
AND SB1.B1_MSBLQL IN ('2') 
AND SD3.D3_UM <> 'MM' 
AND SD3.D3_UM <> ' ' 
AND SD3.D3_CC BETWEEN '' AND 'zzzzzzz'
AND SB2.D_E_L_E_T_= ' '
AND SB2.B2_QATU = 0 
AND SD3.D3_EMISSAO BETWEEN '20180101' AND '20180918' ) 
GROUP BY SB2.B2_FILIAL,SB2.B2_COD,SB1.B1_DESC,SB1.B1_TIPO,SB2.B2_LOCAL,SD3.D3_UM, SB1.B1_UM  
ORDER BY SB2.B2_COD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim! Você consegue estruturar uma condição dentro do `where` combinando `or` e `and`.

Exemplo:

```
and ((not ISNULL(SD3.D3_CC)) and (SD3.D3_CC BETWEEN '' AND 'zzzzzzzzz')
     or ISNULL(SD3.D3_CC))
```

Isso vai funcionar como um "`if..else`", pois você trata com o `or` as duas possibilidades, primeiro o que você precisa, depois negando ela.

O "**`if`**" seria a primeira parte do `or`:

```
(not ISNULL(SD3.D3_CC)) and (SD3.D3_CC BETWEEN '' AND 'zzzzzzzzz')
```

e o "**`else`**" seria a segunda parte do `or`:

```
ISNULL(SD3.D3_CC)
```

Seria como dizer:

```
IF not ISNULL(SD3.D3_CC) THEN

   (SD3.D3_CC BETWEEN '' AND 'zzzzzzzzz')

ELSE /*ISNULL(SD3.D3_CC)*/

   /* neste caso nada seria executado, mas você pode incluir qualquer outro filtro combinado */
```

> Os parênteses por fora são importantes para que a combinação do `or` não se misture com as demais cláusulas do `where`.

Answer (score 0):

Será que assim terá os resultados que pretende?

```
SELECT      DISTINCT 
            SB2.B2_FILIAL
        ,   SB2.B2_COD
        ,   B1_DESC
        ,   SB1.B1_TIPO
        ,   SB2.B2_LOCAL
        ,   CASE WHEN SD3.D3_UM = ' ' THEN SB1.B1_UM ELSE D3_UM END D3_UM
        ,   (
                SELECT  CTT.CTT_DESC01 
                FROM    CTT010 CTT 
                WHERE   CTT_CUSTO = SUBSTRING(' ', 1, 5) 
                    AND CTT.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '
            ) AS CTT_DESC01 
FROM        SB2010 AS SB2 
INNER JOIN  SB1010 AS SB1   ON  SB1.B1_COD      = SB2.B2_COD 
                            AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_  = ' ' 
LEFT JOIN   SD3010 AS SD3   ON  SB2.B2_FILIAL   = SD3.D3_FILIAL 
                            AND SB2.B2_COD      = SD3.D3_COD 
                            AND SB2.B2_LOCAL    = SD3.D3_LOCAL 
                            AND SD3.D_E_L_E_T_  = ' ' 
WHERE       (
                    SB2.B2_FILIAL   = '0301' 
                AND SB2.B2_LOCAL    BETWEEN '03' AND '03' 
                AND SB2.B2_COD      BETWEEN ' ' AND 'zzzzzzzzzzzz' 
                AND SB1.B1_TIPO     NOT IN ('MO','SV') 
                AND SB1.B1_TIPO     IN ('MP') 
                AND SB1.B1_MSBLQL   IN ('2')
                AND (
                            (
                                    SD3.D3_CC   <> ''
                                AND SD3.D3_CC   BETWEEN '' AND 'zzzzzzzzz'
                            )
                        OR  SD3.D3_CC = SD3.D3_CC
                    )
                AND SB2.D_E_L_E_T_  = ' '
                AND SB2.B2_QATU     >= 0.001 
            ) 
        OR  (
                    SD3.D3_FILIAL   = '0301' 
                AND SD3.D3_LOCAL    BETWEEN '03' AND '03' 
                AND SD3.D3_COD      BETWEEN ' ' AND 'zzzzzzzzzzzz' 
                AND SB1.B1_TIPO     NOT IN  ('MO','SV') 
                AND SB1.B1_TIPO     IN ('MP') 
                AND SB1.B1_MSBLQL   IN ('2') 
                AND SD3.D3_UM       <> 'MM' 
                AND SD3.D3_UM       <> ' ' 
                AND SD3.D3_CC       BETWEEN '' AND 'zzzzzzz'
                AND SB2.D_E_L_E_T_  = ' '
                AND SB2.B2_QATU     = 0 
                AND SD3.D3_EMISSAO  BETWEEN '20180101' AND '20180918' 
            ) 
GROUP BY    SB2.B2_FILIAL
        ,   SB2.B2_COD
        ,   SB1.B1_DESC
        ,   SB1.B1_TIPO
        ,   SB2.B2_LOCAL
        ,   SD3.D3_UM
        ,   SB1.B1_UM  
ORDER BY    SB2.B2_COD
```